# jquery submit form inside ajax callback generate popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup, form-submit

I have this code which it submit a generate form on the fly without problems.

```
  var tempForm = $(document.createElement('form'));
  $(tempForm).attr("action", "home.php");
  $(tempForm).attr("target", "_blank");
  $(tempForm).attr("method", "POST");
  $(tempForm).submit();
```

But if I use the same code inside a callback function of ajax, the chrome browser show a pop up message alert (Pop Up Blocked).

```
  var createReserveHandler = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax.php'
  });           
  createReserveHandler.done(function(response) {    
      if (response.responseStatus == "successful") {            
          var tempForm = $(document.createElement('form'));
          $(tempForm).attr("action", "toNewPage.php");
          $(tempForm).attr("target", "_blank");
          $(tempForm).attr("method", "POST");
          $(tempForm).submit();

          location.reload();
      }
      else {.....}
  });
```

The goal to submit of this way is I want open a new page (target _blank) and then reload the origin page, only if response of ajax.php is successfuly.

This is the alert of the browser (chrome).
[image]

What I have to do to avoid it?

Comment: What does the message alert say? It sounds like this is a native security feature to the browser. What exactly are you trying to achieve by submitting the form like that anyway? If you want to make a POST request, why not just $.ajax? Or if you want to redirect, why not update the window.location property?

Comment: The goal to submit of this way is I want open a new page (target _blank) and then reload the origin page.

Comment: In my experience, without an associated DOM event, the browser will block the new window as a popup. You may have to rethink your approach. Maybe open the new window on the original click / submission. Then close it if necessary, and reload the origin using window.opener.